# JQuery Mobile & Google Maps Glitch

Tags: android, google-maps, jquery-mobile, google-maps-api-3

I need to display a Google Map on multiple pages of my mobile app, which is using the JQuery Mobile framework. My app is just an Android app, using a webview, and loading local .html pages (and .js files) stored in the assets directory.

The first time I bring up a page with a map on it, the map looks great and works great.  If I return to this page, or if I open another page with a map on it, the page flickers when loading, and then the map itself glitches.  Initially only about the left 1/3rd of the map tiles are visible.  Dragging the map around only makes the problem worse.  It's as if the map does not know which tiles it should be loading.

Has anyone encountered issues running multiple map pages on the JQuery Mobile framework?  If I had to hazard a guess at this point, I would guess that the AJAX loading system of the JQuery Mobile framework is causing some kind of interference between the pages with regard to the map.  I know there are ways to turn off the AJAX support, but I'd rather not do that if I don't have to.

Comment: I still have not solved this issue, but I have confirmed that it was an AJAX issue.  When I changed my links to rel="external" (therefore disabling AJAX behavior), the problem disappeared.

Answer (score 1):

I have created a map application for my school using the jQuery Mobile Framework. Because of the use of AJAX to load the google map as you scroll, this is what is causing the visual errors and slow loading.

http://ceapps.weber.edu/tourdeweber

Test one of the maps, and let me know if your problem is similar.

I use the `$.mobile.page.prototype.options.domCache = true;` within initializing the JQM to store each page you've visited for faster performance.

Comment: I actually can't get a map to show up anywhere on that mobile site - don't show up on a true web browser on my desktop, or in a webview on my device....

Comment: Are you using the static JavaScript map API? Make sure the div of the map in the webview is being displayed.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow you.  The first time I go to a page with a map, the map displays just fine - so the div is obviously there.  Its only the 2nd+ time that I open a page with a map that the map is distorted - its not invisible or absent.  The map is just loading the wrong set of tiles, only showing a fraction of the map that should be visible.  Sometimes only 1/2 the map is visible, sometimes just about 1/4.  When I scroll the map, it removes visible tiles before they have scrolled off screen.  It is as if the map thinks it is just a little bit up and to the left from where it actually is.

Answer (score 0):

Call `google.maps.event.trigger(mapObj, "resize");` on `pageshow` or `pagechange`

Comment: Be careful when posting copy and paste boilerplate/verbatim answers to multiple questions, these tend to be flagged as "spammy" by the community. If you're doing this then it usually means the questions are duplicates so flag them as such instead: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12886668/419