# Why is the centering of my map off in my jQuery Mobile / Google Maps API3 application?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, jquery-mobile, google-maps-api-3

I have a map powered by Google Maps Javascript API3 in my jQuery Mobile web application. I added a circle with black borders on it.

If you go to this page of my app with the map directly, the map is centered correctly at the center of the circle.

http://goo.gl/XvLST

[image]

If you go to this home page of my app first (http://goo.gl/0IWgE) and then click your way into the page with the map, the map is

1. centered erringly (The map should be centered at the center of the circle).
2. missing an entire area covered in grey.

[image]

Why is the map erring when I click into the page with the map from my home page, but working correctly if I visit the page with the map directly?

I could just not use Ajax to load the map page with `data-ajax='false'`. However, I cannot actually do this because a mobile application does not allow for non-ajax loads.

`google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize')` seems to reposition the map when I enter it into the Chrome Web Developer console, but I am not sure where to call it in my javascript.

Comment: I dont see anything here http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1531353/CS164/mockups/map%20askew/index.html, can you put give a screen shot as when it is badly aligned

Comment: If you click on the link on that page, you should see a map that is badly centered. Oddly, the link is correctly centered if you visit http://goo.gl/XvLST directly.

Comment: I added screenshots in case it would help clarify my issue. Thanks.

Comment: There is nothing wrong in the map as I see it, I think the way you are drawing the circle is creating the issue.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because the page is actully loaded via ajax (when coming from index) - the page event you are using is probably being called before the DOM is totally ready. GMaps expect the page to be ready.

Try using a different event other than pageinit. Looks like pageshow might be a good one (as it runs after any animation has finished)
http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0/docs/api/events.html

Or maybe you could put the call to the maps resize event, in a pageshow event.

Comment: Thank you, I will try that out asap. Just curious, is there a systematic way to view all the events fired for a specific element on a page?

Comment: Not that I know of. Would need to listen to all events and log them. But you need to know all the events that exist for that to work :)

Comment: Yup changing 'pageinit' to 'pageshow' on your page worked for me.

Comment: Thank you! Changing the event to "pageshow" solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Is the page reloading between the home page and the map? If not, and if you're creating or resizing a div, you'll need to call `google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize')` after the div changes (size change or removing a display:none). (edited to show the code to trigger the event, thanks to @Heitor Chang)

Comment: Thanks, but I'm getting this error with `map.resize()` when I call it:  `Uncaught TypeError: Object #<V> has no method 'resize'`. The Google Maps API3 reference also does not mention a `resize()` method associated with a Map object. http://goo.gl/ORciv

Comment: Try google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize') ? It's under "events" of google.maps.Map in the API ref

Comment: Thank you, in which of my functions do you think I should call it? I've tried calling it in `addCircle()` to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

Call `google.maps.event.trigger(mapObj, "resize");` on `pageshow` or `pagechange`

Answer (score 0):

In my case, my workaround is
  `$('#mapdiv').trigger('create');` 
working well. but in other cases I don't know it works.