# Google Maps API3 application why doesn't work fine anymore with a back and forth

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, jquery-mobile, google-maps-api-3

I have an  issue that I couldn't find a solution yet, the google map works the first time I call the page (Single Page App) but than when I go back and forth the map and the markers are right but happen something like happened to this user :

```
1. centered erringly.
2. missing an entire area covered in grey.
```

[Why is the centering of my map off in my jQuery Mobile / Google Maps API3 application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9776761/why-is-the-centering-of-my-map-off-in-my-jquery-mobile-google-maps-api3-applic)

as you can see in the previous post the map is in the corner a bit smaller exactly what happen to me.
Now I show you what I have and what I have tried to solve the issue.

Here it is the code that call the #page-map, in the content of another page called #ListOfPlaces

```
  <a href="#page-map" data-role="button" data-inline="true" onClick="javascript:SetCoordinate('Place1');" >Show Map</a> </p>
```

With this `javascript:SetCoordinate` function I set different Lon. and Lat. that than I use in the function below `center: myLatlng,`

Here my includes in the `Index.html`

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-mobile/jquery.ui.map.js"></script>
```

Here it is my code that shows the map that works fine just the first time:

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
    //funziona ma senza marker
        $(document).on('pageshow', '#page-map', function() {  
        var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(sLat, sLon);
        var myOptions = {
            zoom: 12,
            center: myLatlng,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        }
        $('#map_canvas').fadeOut(300, function(){

          var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
          content: sHTMLPlace
          });
            var map= new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), myOptions);
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: myLatlng,
                title: 'Here is the place'
            });
              //google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize')
             google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {infowindow.open(map,marker
             );

        });
            marker.setMap(map);
            $(this).fadeIn(300);
        });     
        });

</script>
```

According to the documentation I should resize the map once I've created it to solve this specific issue, but it doesn't solve it.

I noticed though, that when I go back with the browser or with the back button and I reload the page (F5) if I click on the link (show map) the map starts to work again, or when I am on the map that it is not showed correctly and I go into the Chrome Web Developer console the map refresh and works fine.

Another thing that I've tried is to simulate the F5 on the "#ListOfPlaces" with the following code

```
function refreshPage()
{
    jQuery.mobile.changePage(window.location.href, {
        allowSamePageTransition: true,
        transition: 'none',
        reloadPage: true
    });
}
```

it doesn't help either. Any suggestion or documentation is accepted, thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Why the pageshow and why the fadeOut / fadeIn? Please indent your code properly and provide a fiddle where we can see the problem.

Comment: First of all thank you for your help, pageshow() because I read is the best place where I can do that, the DOM is built already, fadeOut and in because I like the effect shall I remove it? I idented my code sorry about that.

Comment: I found the solution here https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial but I rewrite almost everything removing fadeOut fadeIn thank you again MrUpsidown you put me in the right path.