# Google Map API v3 off center if reloaded (not the usual 'resize' thing)

Tags: google-maps, jquery-mobile, google-maps-api-3

I read all the similar questions but mine is slightly different. The first time a JQuery Mobile dialog is displayed, the map loads fine inside the usual map_canvas div, but if the dialog is reloaded (i.e. go back and click on the button to open the dialog again), it is displayed only partially, zoomed out to a 3 or 4 and centered around the div's top-left corner.

There is no change in the div size (which is explicitly set) and for good measure a `google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');` is called.

I also tried to initialize the map **after** the dialog is shown but the result is the same.

Button code:

```
$("#dest-map-button").click(function() {
            initializeMap(job_id,"map_canvas");
        }
);
```

Function:

```
function initializeMap(job_id, map_div){

    var pos = arrJobs[job_id].lat_lng.split(',');
    var job_pos = new google.maps.LatLng(pos[0],pos[1]);

    var driverLatLng = lat_lng.split(',');
    var driver_pos = new google.maps.LatLng(driverLatLng[0],driverLatLng[1]);

    var myOptions = {
        zoom: 18,
        center: driver_pos,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
        disableDefaultUI: true
    }

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById(map_div), myOptions);

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: job_pos,
        map: map,
        title: "Job"
    }); 

    var marker2 = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: driver_pos,
        map: map,
        title: "X",
    }); 

    google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
}
```

HTML:

```
    <div data-role="page" id="dialog-destination-map" data-theme="e">
    <div data-role="content">
      <div id="map_canvas" style="height:300px; width:300px; position: relative; margin: 0px auto;">
      map_canvas
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Any ideas?

EDIT: this question seems describing exactly the same problem: [JQuery Mobile & Google Maps Glitch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8918197/jquery-mobile-google-maps-glitch)
But the solution provided (caching) can't be used here as the map might need to change

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After trying everything else, I finally stumbled upon the `pageshow` event. Calling `initializeMap` after all the page transitions are done rather than when clicking the button solved the problem:

```
$('#dialog-destination-map').live('pageshow',function(event){
    initializeMap(job_id,"map_canvas");
    }
);
```

I still wonder how come it was working at the first load then...

Answer (score 2):

I Agree with @peter .. You do not need to create map on each pageshow event.. Instead, try this:

```
$(document).on("pagebeforechange", function()
{
    if(mapObj){
        center = mapObj.getCenter();
    }
});
$("#mapPage").bind("pageshow", function()
{
    google.maps.event.trigger(mapObj, "resize");
    if(center)mapObj.setCenter(center);
});
```

Comment: Guys this is not working for me can you please help ?? here is my question  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23669869/how-change-the-css-of-control-buttons-of-google-map-in-jqm

Answer (score 0):

`var driverLatLng` is being initialized with `lat_lng.split(',');` which hasn't been declared before.

Comment: It's a global var. And as I mentioned, this works at the first load.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to create a new map each time you visit the page. Create the map beforehand, e.g. on `pageinit`. On `pageshow`: `google.maps.event.trigger(mapObj, "resize");`